# get data from json array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having trouble accessing information in a json-Array that I retrieved using php's `json_decode` function.

the json-file looks as follows:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Okay","model":{"results":[{"message":"Okay","balance":0,"openPositions":[[],[]],"firstDepositDate":XXX,"currencySign":"€","email":"X.X@X.com","code":0}]},"result":"success"}
```

I used the following php code to get the contents:

```
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
```

The result print_r displays looks just like what I expect and looks like the json.

However, I cannot figure out to access the variables. Whenever I try something like

```
$test = $json['model']['results']['balance'];
```

the script throws an error, which I can't identify. I already figured out if I access the `$json` variable like so:

```
$test = $json[n]; // returns the nth character, e.g. n = 0 $test = "{", n = 2 $test = "c"
```

The script also did not throw an error if I tried accessing the variable like so:

```
$test = $json['code']; // returns "{"
```

Can someone help me figure out how to navigate this array?

Thanks!

Comment: `$json` contains a string (JSON itself), not an array (result of decoding JSON). Use `$data` instead. Also, as noted in the answer given, `$data['model']['results']` is a regular array; to access its elements, use `$data['model']['results'][0]['message']` syntax.

Comment: thanks - works perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `results` key is a true array, not an unordered map (key/value).  Additionally, you should be accessing the decoded `$data`, not the `$json` string.

This should work for you:

```
$test = $data['model']['results'][0]['balance'];
```

This is what should have tipped you off:

```
{"results":[{"message"
^          ^
|          |
|          \-- Start of an array
|
\-- Start of an object
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - I have tried this before, because I saw similar examples elsewhere, but somehow the script throws an error

Comment: I just edited it.  As @raina77ow pointed out, you want to access `$data`, not the `$json` *string*.

Comment: I'm a bit suprised that this does work for you both... Shouldn't you access the properties with `->`instead like an array?

Comment: @FlorianMoser - `json_decode` defaults to parsing to an object, but if the second parameter is `true` to parses to an array.

Comment: aaah nice, I was a little confused there :)

Answer (score 1):

You recieve an error similar to `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in (...)` right?

json_decode returns an object of the type `stdClass` which is the only object in php (as far as I know) which properties cannot be accessed like an array. You will have to access them as follows:

```
$json = '{"code":0,"message":"Okay","model":{"results":[{"message":"Okay","balance":0,"openPositions":[[],[]],"firstDepositDate":"XX","currencySign":"€","email":"X.X@X.com","code":0}]},"result":"success"}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
var_dump($obj->message); //works
var_dump($obj["message"]); //throws exception
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the JSON array. "firstDepositDate": XXX is not a valid value. Should be a string "XXX".

Also you are trying to the wrong variable. The decoded data should be a PHP array. In this case $data['code'] instead of $json['code']

Comment: the "XXXs" were inserted manually by myself, but of course you are correct!